# Web API Returning a 405. Shouldn't it be a 404?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've got a VendorsController that supports GET (by id) and POST (with a model). They are working as expected when called through the intended routes. However, I noticed that if I add an id to the POST route (ie add "/5" to "api/vendors"), I get a 405, with

Response Body =

{
  "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
}

**Shouldn't this be a 404 Not Found?** The VendorsController does support POST, but not at that URL.

Assuming a 404 is correct, **how can I update my routes to return a 404 instead of a 405?** I believe I could implement a custom ActionSelector to do this, but that feels like overkill.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Vendors")]
public class VendorsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostVendor([FromBody]Vendor vendor)
    {
        var uri = Url.Link("GetVendorById", 1);
        return Created(uri, vendor);
    }

    //GET by Id
    [Route("{id:int:min(1)}", Name="GetVendorById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetVendor(int id)
    {
        return Ok(new Vendor() { Id = id });
    }
}
```

URL returning a 201: POST http://localhost/api/vendors

URL returning a 405: POST http://localhost/api/vendors/5
Returns a 405 both with and without a request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 405 is right because you have a resource that can handle that URL - your GET.

If you had no GET for that resource then a 404 would be correct.

It's not saying the VendorController doesn't support POST, rather that the specific resource you are trying to reach doesn't support POST.